# Ball.setBounds stop to work after componentZOrder() implemention

Tags: java

I can't properly set Ball Bounds with componentZOrder() method

```
public class gamearea extends JFrame{

   private Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
   private Cursor c;

   JLabel ball = new JLabel();
   JLabel desk = new JLabel();
```

Constructor

```
   Gamearea(){
       addMouseMotionListener(this);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
       setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
       setLayout(null);

       desk.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/table.png")));
```

getting image from Folder

```
       ball.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/bball.png")));

       desk.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
```

ball appears but not in the right place

```
       ball.setBounds(356,328,25,25);

       add(desk);
       add(ball);

       setComponentZOrder(desk,1);
       setComponentZOrder(ball,0);

       setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Just to clarify, what does "doesn't appear in the right place" mean? Where does it appear? Also, what are these backticks (`) that are scattered around some lines? My first guess would be that the image isn't the size of the JLabel, so could you provide some info on that aswell?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and turn it into a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to correctly implement setComponentZOrder() in your program, you have to add objects into the panel, then you can use setComponentZOrder.

```
    panel.setLayout(null);

    panel.add(desk);
    panel.add(ball);

    panel.setComponentZOrder(ball,0);
    panel.setComponentZOrder(desk,1);

    setContentPane(panel);

    desk.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    ball.setBounds(375,232,25,25);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the layout manager for the content pane of your gamearea class?If you have not set it, it defaults to a BorderLayout, and then when you add two components to it, the first one goes in CENTER, and the second will replace the first at CENTER.

Your component should not be a subclass of JFrame. Have it extend JPanel instead and use the proper LayoutManager to place the children in the panel, and add that panel to a JFrame that you then display.

Also, you should follow Java conventions and start the name of your class with a capital letter (GameArea or Gamearea, not gamearea).